# Sub queries in jpa Query

Tags: jpa, spring-boot, crud

This is my database query

```
select v.FK_EQUIPMENT, sum(fuel) as fuel,v1.END_TIME_METER
from vp_reports v ,
(select distinct FK_EQUIPMENT,END_TIME_METER
from vp_reports  v
where MODIFIED_ON in (select  max(MODIFIED_ON)
                                    from vp_reports
                                    where END_TIME_METER is not null
                                    group by FK_EQUIPMENT )) v1
where v.FK_EQUIPMENT = v1.FK_EQUIPMENT
group by v.FK_EQUIPMENT,v1.END_TIME_METER;
```

and I am writing the same in jpa

```
@Query("select new Reports (v.fkEquipment, sum(fuel) as fuel, v1.endTimeMeter) "
        + " from Reports v ,  "
        + " (select distinct fkEquipment, endTimeMeter from Reports v "
        + " where modifiedOn in ( select max(modifiedOn) from Reports where endTimeMeter is not null "
        + " group by fkEquipment)) v1 "
        + " where v.fkEquipment = v1.fkEquipment "
        //+ " and v.mrfId= ?1 "
        //+ " and v.shift in (?2) and v.fkStatusDei= ?3 and v.assignedDate between to_date(?4, 'yyyy-mm-dd') and to_date(?5, 'yyyy-mm-dd') "
        + " GROUP BY v.fkEquipment,v1.endTimeMeter ")
List<Reports> findByMrfIdAndShiftAndFkStatusDeiAndAssignedDate(String mrfId, String shift, long fkStatusDei, String from, String to);
```

and getting below error -

> Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException:
>   unexpected token: ( near line 1, column 107 [select new Reports
>   (v.fkEquipment, sum(fuel) as fuel, v1.endTimeMeter)  from
>   com.dei.domain.Reports v ,   (select distinct fkEquipment,
>   endTimeMeter from com.dei.domain.Reports v  where modifiedOn in (
>   select max(modifiedOn) from com.dei.domain.Reports where endTimeMeter
>   is not null  group by fkEquipment)) v1  where v.fkEquipment =
>   v1.fkEquipment  GROUP BY v.fkEquipment,v1.endTimeMeter ]  at
>   org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException.convert(QuerySyntaxException.java:91)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter.throwQueryException(ErrorCounter.java:109)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.parse(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:304)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:203)

Could you please help me ? or **how do I convert my DB query to JPQL?**

Comment: I am not sure this is a native querry. The corect syntax to create a native querry should be @Querry(value="your query", nativeQuery = true)

Comment: That is a JPQL query NOT "native" (SQL). You cannot use subqueries in the FROM clause in JPQL as any JPQL documentation would tell you. Also native queries do not have JPQL Constructor notation in the SELECT clause

Comment: @NeilStockton Do you have any other solution to achieve this?

Comment: @rinuthomaz Use a native querry, like in my first comment